# Orika mapping jdbc ResultSet Bean

Tags: jdbc, orika

I want my Java layer to talk to my DB using stored procedures.  The stored procedures act as a compatibility layer so that I can run two different versions of the application expecting two different schemas on top of the same database.

To do that I wanted to use Orika to quickly map from a JDBC ResultSet to on of my Beans.

I have written this test code so far:
        @Test
    public void testSelectAndMap() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(dataSource);
        try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            try(Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {

```
            try (ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select 1 as internalTestPojoId, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as now")) {
                result.next();
                MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
                mapperFactory.classMap(ResultSet.class, InternalTestPojo.class)
                        .byDefault()
                        .field("internalTestPojoId:{getInt('internalTestPojoId')|getInt('internalTestPojoId')|type=" + int.class.getName() + "}", "internalTestPojoId")
                        .field("now:{getTimestamp('now')|getTimestamp('now')|type=" + Timestamp.class.getName() + "}", "now")
                        .register();
                MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
                InternalTestPojo pojo = mapper.map(result, InternalTestPojo.class);
                Assert.assertEquals(pojo.internalTestPojoId, 1);
                Assert.assertEquals(pojo.now, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime() / 1000 * 1000));

            }
```

This works great it is fast, but it does not really take that much less of my time coding then writing the ResultSet to Bean code myself. But if I could automatically generate the mapping it would save me a lot of time.

I looked at `IntrospectorPropertyResolver`.  I wrote code like this:

```
protected Property getProperty(java.lang.reflect.Type type, String expr,
                               boolean isNestedLookup, Property owner) throws MappingException {
    Property property = null;
    try {
        property = super.getProperty(type, expr, isNestedLookup, null);
    } catch (MappingException e) {
        try {
            property = super.resolveInlineProperty(type,
                    expr + ":{getInt('" + expr + "')|getInt('" + expr + "')|type=" + int.class);

        } catch (MappingException subE) {
            throw e; // throw the original exception
        }
    }
    return property;
}
```

This is nice, Orika automatically determines the property name on the bean and gives it to me in expr.  But it does not tell me the type.  Nor does it tell me what I am trying to map to.  I just have to pretend that in this case the target is a ResultSet.

1. How do I know the type of the expr I am trying to put data into?  If it is a `String` I'll make the inline binding call `ResultSet.getString("expr")` and tell Orika to use `java.lang.String`.  If it is a Timestamp I'll make the inline binding call `Resulset.getTimestamp("expr")` and tell Orika to use `Timestamp`
2. How do I know that I am trying to map from `ResultSet` to `InternalTestPojo` versus for example `Map` to `InternalTestPojo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you to do is to use a custom class map builder extending the default one, so you can add fields automatically to your class map by overriding byDefault method.

This an simple example to use Annotations with Orika: https://gist.github.com/elaatifi/5212119

You don't need to use Reflection you can use the PropertyResolver to look for all properties of InternalTestPojo, and for each one build the counter part porperty for ResultSet and add it to the class map.

To build the counter part property you could use the Property.Builder.
The getter method for the property can be concluded from the type.

Hope this can help !

Comment: I don't have the reputation to mark your answer as correct.  I was able to create the mapping using a custom class map build and getting the field information from the PropertyResolver